# How to use the QT library on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I have a piece of code that uses the QT library. More specifically, it contains the lines

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>
```

and some others that I believe are related to the Qt library. The code comes with some kind of a make file (I believe it's for some Microsoft editor) with the lines:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

I'm trying to compile the code using gcc on my Ubuntu (16.10) system. I've tried giving the compiler option -lQtCore, but I get an error:

```
fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
fatal error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory
```

Which packages I need to install and which libraries I need to link with gcc to make it work?

Comment: The some kind of make file is likely a Qt project file.  You want to read up on `qmake`.  `qmake` will parse a .pro project file and generate a suitable `Makefile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is a Qt project file. Build the project with these commands:

```
qmake <Qt project file.pro>
make
```

Answer (score 2):

> QT       += core gui
>   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

That resembles a `.pro` file, and can be built using QtCreator.